# Design pattern for 2 successive ToS type screens upon logging in

Tags: ios

Upon logging in successfully on my iPad app, I must present the user with 2 successive screens of information. These screens are just walls of static text using a `UITextView`. After accepting/nexting past the first screen, the second screen must appear right after.

I have thought about having a modal segue for the first screen with a nav bar 'next' button in the top right. After 'nexting', the next screen could be a push segue and then after 'nexting' the second screen, we could push segue into the main content.

I'm not sure about how to handle a cancel/signout button on the ToS screens. I can't place it in the top left of nav bar because that looks strange for the second ToS screen since it will have a back arrow beside it.

Comment: I'd recommend a UIToolbar at the bottom of the screen with UIBarButtons on it.  So keep your navigation between the two pages on top, Cancel/ Accept buttons on the bottom (only show Accept on page 2, of course! :-) )

Comment: Thanks, @KeithKurak. I ended up going with the UIToolbar suggestion. I added the tool bar to the bottom of the screen and on the left side I have my cancel button and on the right side I have my next button. Answer if you want, and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a UIToolbar at the bottom of the screen with UIBarButtons on it. So keep your navigation between the two pages on top, Cancel/ Accept buttons on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

1. Modal upon first successful login to present a navigation controller containing two controllers which contain the ToS texts.
2. Upon clicking accept on the first one, the second is pushed.
3. Upon clicking accept on the second one, the modal dismisses and your app shows its main content.

Comment: This is what I mentioned as what I was thinking. Where would you suggest placing 'next', 'cancel' buttons on each screen?

Comment: @AdamJohns Reset your test device. Go through the new device setup. The buttons are placed in the navigation bar, and sometimes in the content view too if not too obvious. For left to right cultures, the next button should be on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I've used is to have a root "container" NavigationController that uses Login as root VC.

Login controller then asks "legal stuff was presented?" If yes, replace root view controller of NavController with my first "app content" VC.

If no, replace root view controller of NavController with first "legal" screen. First legal screen has a modal-show of second screen (via button), and second legal screen has a "ok" and "cancel" buttons. Ok = replace root view controller of NavController with first "app content" VC, Cancel = log user out and replace root view controller of NavController with the Login VC again.

Some helpful code for this: presenting a VC from storyboard by getting it by Storyboard ID string:

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

NSString* storyboardVcId = “IdFromStoryboard”;
UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: storyboardVcId];

[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[vc] animated:NO];
```